# Calling an ASP.Net web api from a ASP.Net MVC web app. MVC web client is not building the URL properly so getting not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I run my web api method using Postman passing in my URL, it works fine - it returns the value of '5' which I expect since the call returns just a single integer. Also at the very bottom I include another method of my web api that I run using Postman and it too works just fine.

http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog/validatelogin/DemoUser1/DemoUser1Password/169.254.102.60/

[image]
[image]

However, in the client - an Asp.Net MVC method, when building the URL, it is DROPPING the "/api/profileandblog" part. Note: I'm using "attribute routing" in the web api.

---

Here is the Asp.Net MVC method to call the web api:

I stop it on this line so I can see the error details: if (result1.IsSuccessStatusCode)

It's INCORRECTLY building the URL as: http://localhost:56224/validatelogin/DemoUser1/DemoUser1Password/169.254.102.60/

It's dropping the: "/api/profileandblog" part that should follow 56224.
So it give's me the Not found.

Why does it drop it? It has the localhost:56224 correct.

[image]

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SignIn(SignInViewModel signInViewModel)
    {
        int returnedApiValue = 0;
        User returnedApiUser = new User();
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        string myIpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[2].ToString();

        try
        {
            if (!this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid"))
            {
                ViewBag.errormessage = "Error: captcha entered is not valid.";
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signInViewModel.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(signInViewModel.Password))
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog");
                        string restOfUrl = "/validatelogin/" + signInViewModel.Username + "/" + signInViewModel.Password + "/" + myIpAddress + "/";

                        // Call the web api to validate the sign in.
                        // Sends back a -1(failure), -2(validation issue) or the UserId(success) via an OUTPUT parameter.
                        var responseTask1 = client.GetAsync(restOfUrl);

                        responseTask1.Wait();

                        var result1 = responseTask1.Result;

                        if (result1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var readTask1 = result1.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                            readTask1.Wait();

                            returnedApiValue = Convert.ToInt32(readTask1.Result);

                            if (returnedApiValue == -2)
                            {
                                ViewBag.errormessage = "You entered an invalid user name and/or password";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // I have the 'user id'.
                                // Continue processing...                                  
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error on signing in. 'validatelogin'. Please contact the administrator.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(signInViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

---

Per the suggestion about not having headers, I used another tutorial (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-in-asp-net-mvc-using-http-client/) and it has the code for defining the headers. But it is coded slightly different - using async Task<> on the method definition. I was not using async in my prior version.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(SignInViewModel signInViewModel)
    {
        int returnedApiValue = 0;
        User returnedApiUser = new User();
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        string myIpAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[2].ToString();

        try
        {
            if (!this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid"))
            {
                ViewBag.errormessage = "Error: captcha entered is not valid.";
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signInViewModel.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(signInViewModel.Password))
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224/api/profileandblog");
                        string restOfUrl = "/validatelogin/" + signInViewModel.Username + "/" + signInViewModel.Password + "/" + myIpAddress + "/";

                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        // Call the web api to validate the sign in.
                        // Sends back a -1(failure), -2(validation issue) or the UserId(success) via an OUTPUT parameter.
                        HttpResponseMessage result1 = await client.GetAsync(restOfUrl);

                        if (result1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var readTask1 = result1.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
                            readTask1.Wait();

                            returnedApiValue = Convert.ToInt32(readTask1.Result);

                            if (returnedApiValue == -2)
                            {                                    
                                ViewBag.errormessage = "You entered an invalid user name and/or password";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // I have the 'user id'.  
                                // Do other processing....
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error on signing in. 'validatelogin'. Please contact the administrator.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(signInViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

It now has a header but still NOT building the URL properly as it is not including the "/api/profileandblog" part.

[image]

---

Here is the web api and the method being called:

```
    namespace GbngWebApi2.Controllers
    {
       [RoutePrefix("api/profileandblog")]
       public class WebApi2Controller : ApiController
       {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("validatelogin/{userName}/{userPassword}/{ipAddress}/")]
        public IHttpActionResult ValidateLogin(string userName, string userPassword, string ipAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                IHttpActionResult httpActionResult;
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;

                int returnValue = 0;

                // Will either be a valid 'user id" or a -2 indicating a validation issue.
                returnValue = dataaccesslayer.ValidateLogin(userName, userPassword, ipAddress);

                httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnValue);

                httpActionResult = ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);

                return httpActionResult;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's the network tab of the client browser before I hit the button to fire of the Asp.Net MVC method.

[image]

The network tab of the client browser after I hit the button to fire of the Asp.Net MVC method and it fails.

[image]

---

Here's another example of Postman executing another method of my api just fine.

[image]

Comment: You're not setting any headers. My guess is that you should look into that. Also, and I can't stress this enough, it's probably not best that you call an API by passing security credentials in the url

Comment: New with this so I used this as a reference and it does not indicate using headers. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-get-method-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: I found another tutorial with the header code. I executed that code which I show above. Now returns: {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RjpcUHJpdmF0ZVxHYm5nXFByb2ZpbGVBbmRPckJsb2dcRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnRcR2JuZ1dlYkFwaTJcR2JuZ1dlYkFwaTJcdmFsaWRhdGVsb2dpblxEZW1vVXNlcjFcRGVtb1VzZXIxUGFzc3dvcmRcMTY5LjI1NC4xMDIuNjBc?=
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2020 14:05:51 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 5044
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}

Comment: It has the headers. But same original issue that it is not resolving to the complete URL I am building. See the new picture I included above.

Comment: If you run this, and open Google Dev tools before you hit whatever it is to call this function, what does the Network tab tell you?

Comment: James - nothing in the network tab just before I'm ready to hit the button to fire off the client code which will fire off the web api. I included the picture above.

Comment: I'm afraid the only other thing I can think of is that it's not liking the password have `.`'s in it.

Comment: That would be the ip address. And it works in Postman.

Comment: I got it to work by setting this as:  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56224"); and setting the string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/validatesignin/" + signInViewModel.Username + "/" + signInViewModel.Password + "/" + myIpAddress + "/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by setting this as: client.BaseAddress = new Uri("localhost:56224"); and setting the string restOfUrl = "/api/profileandblog/validatesignin/" + signInViewModel.Username + "/" + signInViewModel.Password + "/" + myIpAddress + "/";